# Center Child dynamic divs

Tags: html, css

I have to centered the div horizontally. `cont1` div is parent div . it will take the width of device. and `cont2` is child div it will take the width according to its content. 
and the number of `child` div is dynamic . all the divs are centered perfectly . But the issue is with last div. I want the last div at left side. I have tried lots of techniques.
But unable to fix that .

I dont want to use javascript or jquery .

Here is fiddle link
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dzgg4x1n/)

Here is html

```
<div class="cont1">
    <div class="cont2">
        <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
          <div class="child">  </div>
         <div class="child">  </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is Css

```
.cont1 {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 840px;
}
.cont2 {
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
}
.child{
     display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    max-width: 230px;
    width: 30%;
height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dzgg4x1n/7/)

css

```
.cont1 {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    width: 840px;
    text-align: left; /* make it left */
}

.cont2 {
    /* display: inline; remove this */
    max-width:600px; /* add this */
    margin:auto; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: but last child div should start from left

Comment: it is started from left..:) does it solves your problem?

Comment: I have to centered the div horizontally. cont1 div is parent div . it will take the width of device. and when there will be a large device the width of cont1 will increase then there should be 4 or 5 child div in one row

Comment: just give width to `.cont2` example to match your requirement `min-width:600px; max-width:840px;` it will fulfill all your cases.

Comment: That is ok but the width of cont1 is also dynamic and it will increase according to device. in that case i need to show 4 or 5 child div in single row

Comment: your `.cont1` will never take full width of browser as u explicitly given `width:840px` to it with a `min-width:600px`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67002/discussion-between-ap-singh-and-4dgaurav).

Answer (score 0):

Put the `text-align: center;` from `.cont1` and replace the `text-align: left` on `.cont2` with it.

```
.cont1 {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 600px;
position: relative;
width: 840px;
}

.cont2 {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzgg4x1n/10/)

Comment: but cont2 has also moved to left. cont2 should be in center